# Django ModelForm save using db_alias param "using"

Tags: database, django, alias, django-forms

Is it possible to save ModelForm object data with db_alias different than "default"

```
my_form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
my_form.save(commit=True,using="db_alias")
```

as well as saving data with model instance?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: Unfortunately ,you can't save the form that way. If you form doesn't contain ForeignKey or m2m fields (or you are controlling them yourself, for example using an autocompletefield, etc.), you can handle the object after the form:

```
_obj = _form.save(commit=False)
_obj.save(using=_db_alias)
```

Long answer: If you want the modelform to behave like a normal one with ForeignKeys and m2m-fields, something like:

```
# The form's foreign_keys and m2m-fields get the data from the db_alias database
# and evertyhing is sdisplayed correctly on the template.
_form = myModelForm(request, db_alias=_db_alias)

# The form saves to the correct DB and foreigns & M2ms are matched correctly in this DB
# _form.save()
```

Although this would be ideal, you just can't use this behaviour. There are many DB hooks that you need to alter in Django code to get this working. What I have done is to create a new modelform class from the base modelform, and get the (partial) functionality described before.

Hope this helps, and also hopping a better solution comes soon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hope it will get better soon.